# Need to change conditional formatting with macro

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Can someone tell me why it LOOKS like this worked when I look at the conditional formatting for cell W29, but the cell in my workbook isn't actually turning red when it should? (I had originally used Conditional Formatting to set it up so that cell W29 (actually merged cells W29:AC29) turns red if the date entered in cell W29 becomes less than 60 days out from the current date. Of course, that has worked perfectly for the last two years. HOWEVER, I'm trying to change it to 90 days out, and I have a gazillion worksheets to change, so I'm trying to use a macro. I clearly don't know what I'm doing...Please help :(

```
Sub fixped()
    
    Set MyRange = Range("W29:AC29")
    MyRange.FormatConditions.Delete
    MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="W29<TODAY()+90"
    MyRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: `Formula1:="=W29<TODAY()+90"` you forgot the `=` in the formula itself

Answer (score 1):

Insert the cell absolute address.  $W29

```
Sub fixped()
    
    Set MyRange = Range("W29:AC29")
    MyRange.FormatConditions.Delete
    MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$W29<TODAY()+90"
    MyRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub
```